# when app launched default layout first flashes before my app sets content view

Tags: android, layout

I am making an app which has architecture like this

there are two activities

a) BaseActivity

b) MainActivity

BaseActivity extends Activity

and

mainActivity extends BaseActivity

now

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
   onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance) {
      super.OnCreate(SavedInstance) 
      setContentView(R.Layout.screen_main)
   }
}
```

and

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
  onCreate(Bundle SavedInstance) {
      super.OnCreate(SavedInstance)

      //not doing anything else in on create 
  }
}
```

now when i launch the app MainActivity is called how ever before the app sets content view to `R.Layout.screen_main`
for like a frustrating 2 secs it first flashes a white screen with tittle and then it executes `setContentView(R.Layout.screen_main);`

I have a feeling it sets content view to a default layout from android while the app is processing in the super.`OnCreate`  in case of most apps instead it shows a black screen without any  tittlebar  of the app however in my app it first shows a default android layout of white screen and tittle bar and then it loads my layout 
so my question is

why so and what should i do so that the first thing the app does of all other things is it sets my layout so that that when we launch the app it shows my view and does not first show white screen with tittle even a blank black screen instaed of this screen will do

Comment: put setContentView(R.layout.screen_main) under super.OnCreate(SavedInstance) in your BaseActivity class instead of MainActivity. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of `super.onCreate()` call, Whenever your **MainActivity** Executes

Because of `super.onCreate()`

BaseActivity's onCreate will get executed, so because of that your BaseActivity content will be displayed.
And Whenever it reaches the line

```
setContentView(layout)
```

It will set the new content for your current Activity `i.e MainActivity`

Whenever you want common menus in all of your activity, it is recommened to use because you are setting the Content, But you are setting the content in the BaseActivity which makes it content Display on the current Activity when `super.onCreate()` call .
 So Don't extend with BaseActivity instead extend Activity

Comment: i wish to keep the the architecture of the app same is ther any workaround with which even a black screen in the start of the activity will do i tried setting content view to a blank black screen in the oncreate of base activity and then setting content view again to sreen_main in oncreate of main activity  but it did not affect the app at all then i also changed the order of execution of super in oncreate i tried to execute super after it has setcontentview in main activity even that did not help

Comment: @aman Don't set any contentview for BaseActivity then. just call super.onCreate() in the onCreate() method of BaseActivity

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

and

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity
```

Comment: But i don't wish to change the architechture ,,,what i did was moved the code of setContentView from mainactivity to base activity however it did not make a diff ,,

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you are calling `MainActivity` somewhere in `BaseActivity` and it's called recursively all over again.